How to import my supabase db types in edge functions (Deno)?
How can I (properly) use the locally downloaded types of my supabase db for use in an Edge Functions environment (Deno) to provide autocomplete suggestions in VS Code?
I tried doing it similarly to how it was done in my react supabase:
import "jsr:@supabase/functions-js/edge-runtime.d.ts"
import { createClient, SupabaseClient } from 'jsr:@supabase/supabase-js@2'
import { Database } from "../_types/supabase.ts";

const supabase = createClient<Database>(
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL') ?? '',
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_ANON_KEY') ?? '',
      { global: { headers: { Authorization: req.headers.get('Authorization')! } } }
    )


But it doesn't seem to be working as VS Code isn't suggesting an autocomplete of my tables if I type it.

Can you [edit] the question to clarify the problem — and include a [mre]? The content of all relevant files should be included directly in the question, and I don’t see any information about where you expect IntelliSense suggestions and aren’t getting any from the language server.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@jsejcksn createClient<Database>, adding the Database types is supposed to make the resulting supabase value have intellisense and types awareness. Instead, it's still any

Ok after lots of work, and trying everything from this github discussion, the thing that immediately worked for me was opening my supabase-functions workspace directly, in a new vs-code window.
Definitely need the vscode deno extension.
So the folder that contains .vscode/settings.json and my supabase/functions folders. Is a specific project/workspace. The intellisense doesn't scope to that directories settings - if it is contained inside a larger project, and you open that project's higher parent folder, then drill down into these supabase functions.
You have to specifically open vscode to the folder with your supabase/ directory. Worked on my machine.
